# Script to modify php array elements in hundreds of files

Tags: php, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have some severely deprecated PHP code that I'm sifting through. One of the problems that I have is hundreds of errors like this:

`[Mon Dec 09 07:00:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in /home/srv/site.local/content/online.php on line 171, referer: http://site.local/index.php`

These result in the practice of a previous coder of calling arrays like this:

```
$array[some_element]
```

instead of:

```
$array['some_element']
```

So I know how to fix that by going through each file and adding the quotes, over, and over, and over again. My question is how to write script for this. I imagine this might be a sed or awk script, but I'm not sure. I'm going to start working on a sed as soon as I'm done posting this, but any suggestions?

Comment: why do not you just replace **$array[some_element]** with this **$array['some_element']** using any editor?

Comment: Because I'd be here all day. This is throughout the site; and it's a big site.. I use vim. It probably is script-able in vim. I do have bluefish, though. I would like to get my head around sed and awk, but the point is to get it done. Good idea. I take a look at bluefish and see if it lets me do a global replace.

Comment: Here's where I'm at with awk right now, which looks more suited than sed:

`awk '{c += sub(/\[[.*]\]/,"[element]") }1' content/testfile.php | less`

which is not quite doing anything yet, but the point is to at least "hit" the array elements first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about php, so I'm not sure whether this solution is a particularly good one:

```
sed  "s|\[[ ]*|\[\'|g;s|[ ]*\]|\'\]|g" test.in
```

example of use:

```
[fixarraysubscript $] cat test.in
$array[some_element]

$name1[index]

$name2[index]


$name3[ id ]

$name4[ id2 ]

[fixarraysubscript $]
[fixarraysubscript $] sed  "s|\[[ ]*|\[\'|g;s|[ ]*\]|\'\]|g" test.in
$array['some_element']

$name1['index']

$name2['index']


$name3['id']

$name4['id2']

[fixarraysubscript $]
```

obviously my input file is somewhat contrived. If this doesn't work for you, please feel free to post some real input.

Comment: Thank you! That hits the simpler cases and does what I need to do with them. That will probably clear up 95% of my errors.

Comment: ok, great. I now see your more complex example, and this won't correctly transpose the first outer brackets of something like: $tsms_cats[$data['t_s']]['color']. I guess it depends on how many examples you have like this...

Comment: Right. I just ran it and it turns that bit into:

$tsms_cats['$data['t_s']'][''name'']

So I'm working on the regex a bit. I'm pretty sure I can limit it to word characters and avoid that.

Comment: I thought I would have to use back references for this. Interesting how you avoided that.

Comment: Well, maybe I do... This is getting really close. Thank you for your help:

`sed  "s|\[\(\w\)|\[\'\1|g;s|\(\w\)\]|\1\'\]|g" content/testfile.php | grep tsms_cats`

`...$tsms_cats[$data['t_s']]['color']...`

Comment: ok, yep, I see. You probably want to match white space between the word and the bracket, e.g. `sed "s|\[[ ]*\(\w\)|\[\'\1|g;s|\(\w\)[ ]*\]|\1\'\]|g"` to avoid missing the cases like: $name3[ id ].

Answer (score 0):

This may work with `gnu awk`

```
echo '$array[some_element]' | awk '{print gensub(/\$([^[]+)\[([^]]+)]/,"$\\1["q"\\2"q"]","g")}' q="'"
$array['some_element']
```

For your file

```
awk '{print gensub(/\$([^[]+)\[([^]]+)]/,"$\\1["q"\\2"q"]","g")}' q="'" file
```

or

```
awk '{print gensub(/\$([^[]+)\[([^]]+)]/,"$\\1[\x27\\2\x27]","g")}' file
```

EDIT: Changed regex to reflect variable array name.

Comment: "function gensub undefined", but I think the regex is getting close. Thank you. I might not have been clear, BTW, but this syntax was used on every array in every file on a large website. Plus, to complicate things further, a few arrays _do_ have quotes in them. I haven't seen any multidimensional arrays in there yet, but I bet there are some...

Comment: Of course if I can get something that works one file I can just throw it in a bash for loop to get all...

Comment: Here's the most complex example I see so far:

`$tsms_cats[$data[t_s]]['color']`

So I need to figure out how to replace that with:

`$tsms_cats[$data['t_s']]['color']`

As well as the simpler ones. I suspect that this will be multiple awks in a bash script by the time I get done. Still better than going through and changing all of this "by hand" though, IMO.

Comment: If you do not have `gnu awk` why you seen `undefined` using `gensub`. Your code would be hard to match.